# TikZ calendar day list downward with labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calendar

I'm wanting to make a vertical calendar with tasks listed on certain days. For instance, how can I make the code below list a task on February 19th?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[top=15mm, bottom=15mm, left=15mm, right=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \calendar [dates=2016-02-01 to 2016-02-29, day list downward, month label left]
    if (weekend) [black!25]
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to give your calendar a name with the option `name=mycalendar`. Then you can reference the dates. In your example with `mycalendar-2016-02-19`. Using this name you can then place a node.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[top=15mm, bottom=15mm, left=15mm, right=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \calendar [dates=2016-02-01 to 2016-02-29, day list downward, month label left, name=mycalendar]
    if (weekend) [black!25];
    \node [anchor=base west] at (mycalendar-2016-02-19.base east) {\textbf{My Task}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: calendar]